# How to nicely align my blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks for the vibrant and fantastic community we have here. 
I am working on a project in which I need to nicely align all my blocks one below another to not break my design.

I reached a point where I am a little bit stuck and do not really not to to figure this out.

Here is my code :

html

```
<div class="homepage-wrapper">
    <div class="homepage-top-category-container">
        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-title">
            <span id="homepage-top-category-container-title">Popular aisles</span>
        </div>
        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-list">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-a">
                        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item-btn">
                            Browse perishables
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-b">
                        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item-btn">
                            Browse household
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-c">
                        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item-btn">
                            Browse pets
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-d">
                        <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item-btn">
                            Browse baby & toddler
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="homepage-banner">

<div class="homepage-banner-grid" id="homepage-banner-hc-description">
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item1">
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
    <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
<span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item2">
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
    <img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
<span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items" id="homepage-banner-hc-description-item3">
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon">
<img src="http://bailbondsstatesboro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/24_7_service.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
<div class="homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text">
<span>Vivamus massa felis, eleifend quis rhoncus id, finibus id velit.</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is css :

```
.homepage-wrapper {
    max-width: 1043px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-title {
    color: #808080;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#homepage-top-category-container-title {
    color: ##808080;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-list > div {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-item {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px #d0d0ce;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-item:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
}
#homepage-top-category-container-item-a {
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
}
#homepage-top-category-container-item-b {
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
}
#homepage-top-category-container-item-c {
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
}
#homepage-top-category-container-item-d {
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
}
.homepage-top-category-container-item-btn {
    background-color: #cde5d9;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d0ce;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d0ce;
}


.homepage-banner-grid{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items{
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 15px;
    }
/*
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
    }
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items:last-child{
    margin-right:0px;
    }
*/  
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item1{
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    }
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item2{
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
#homepage-banner-hc-description-item3{
    background-color: orange;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    }
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text{
    display: flex;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    }
.homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text span {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate help to align the 4 top-blocks with the 3 bottom-blocks. I would like the whole thing to be nicely aligned so it'll looks professional.

JSfiddle here -->   https://jsfiddle.net/hkz6g5sn/

Thanks.

****************EDIT****************************

it currently looks like this on my screen :

[image: What I have ....]

And I want to do this :

[image: want to do this !]

Comment: What's the problem? What does "nicely aligned" mean, and how is that different from how it looks now?

Comment: I want all rows to be aligned : like starting from the left ( top block) , the first row has to be aligned with the first row at the bottom , and the same thing for the last row at on the top-block ; has to be aligned with the last row , at the bottom

Comment: @GabrielD. Like in my answer? Its unclear what you are asking

Comment: Do you mean the 24/7 boxes need to be left aligned instead of centered?

Comment: Screenshot of how it currently looks?

Comment: [this is how it currently looks](https://s28.postimg.org/mdhh9f1h9/Untitled_1.jpg) To be honest that looks good.  What needs to move?

Comment: @DR01D , no , I uploaded a picture with annotations of what I am trying to do. Did you obtain with no code edit ?

Comment: @theHussle Just uploaded what it looks like on my screen and what Im trying to do

Comment: @Pepe Sorry for my question not being clear. I uploaded a pictures with annotation of what I'm trying to do

Comment: no answer ... ?

Comment: Do you want to shrink the 3 column row? because the alignment might be odd if the middle one is aligned, but the others not.

Comment: @theHussle can you show me how it looks like if this is done ?

Answer (score 1):

[image] Bit of a hack but this will do it, any reason your not using a library to handle the grids? you could solve this with media queries, but it'll take abit of code.

```
   .homepage-wrapper {
        max-width: 1043px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-title {
        color: #808080;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-title {
        color: ##808080;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-list > div {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        border: solid 1px #d0d0ce;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item:hover {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-a {
        width: 240px;
        height: 360px;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-b {
        width: 240px;
        height: 360px;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-c {
        width: 240px;
        height: 360px;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-d {
        width: 240px;
        height: 360px;
    }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item-btn {
        background-color: #cde5d9;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 10px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #d0d0ce;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d0ce;
    }

    .homepage-banner-grid{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }

    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items{
        height: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;   
        max-width: 328px; // here
        }

      .margin-left {
        margin-left: 15px; // here
      }
    /*
    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items:first-child{
        margin-left:0px;
        }
    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items:last-child{
        margin-right:0px;
        }
    */  
    #homepage-banner-hc-description-item1{
        background-color: pink;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    #homepage-banner-hc-description-item2{
        background-color: green;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    #homepage-banner-hc-description-item3{
        background-color: orange;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items-icon{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        }
    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text{
        display: flex;
        height: 140px;
        text-align: center;
        }
    .homepage-banner-hc-description-items-text span {
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
```

}

If you just add .margin-left to second and third item, leaving width at 100%

[image]

Comment: Otherwise another solution is to leave the width alone, and separate the left margin and only attach it to the second and third, the problem appears to be a 30px margin on the red one, pushing alignment out for the others.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks. I will implement this in my project ^_^. This is not what I expected , but it'll do the work.

Comment: No problem, if it works out for you please mark answer as correct. All the best.

Comment: wait ! this is just what Im trying to do !. the last impae you posted with all columns aligned ! What is the css ? The last image you posted is what I was trying to do

Comment: What is the correct css to achieve a similar result just like in the last picture you sent ?